# ASP.NET MVC миграция базы данных в 3-уровневой архитектуре

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, архитектура, asp.net-core-mvc

Задумался вот над таким вопросом.

Допустим, создаём 3-уровневую архитектуру в ASP.NET MVC: слой доступа к БД (DAL), слой бизнес-логики (BLL) и слой представления (WEB). ORM используем Entity Framework. Контекст базы объявляем в проекте DAL, строка подключения в конфиге проекта WEB.

Как в этом случае настроить миграции базы?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется сам разобрался. 
Кому интересно, вот как сделал. Реализовал на ASP.NET Core 2.1, потому что там встроенный механизм DI, а со сторонними возиться не хотелось.

1. Где-нибудь рядом с контекстом БД (в проекте Project.DAL) добавляем такой класс:

   ```
   public class DataContextDbFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>
   {
       DataContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
       {
           var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../Project.WEB"))
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true).Build();
           var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer<DataContext>(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
           return new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
       }
   }
   ```
2. В файл проекта Project.DAL.csproj добавляем такие два пункта:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
   ```

Эти референсы нужны для класса DataContextDbFactory, чтобы работал ConfigurationBuilder.

3. Делаем запускаемым проектом Project.WEB (это слой представлений). В Солюшн Эксплоререре кликаем правой кнопкой и выбираем "Set as StartUp Project".
4. Всё, можно добавлять миграции командой в консоли PM

   ```
   Add-Migration InitData -project Project.DAL -context DataContext
   ```

Для обновления базы, соответственно:

```
Update-Database -project Project.DAL -context DataContext
```